# Retrieve MYSQL field array with "Like"

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, sql-like

I have pages saved in mysql db, and one of the fields is an array of tags, for each page, which was in hopes to help with a site search.

I'm getting an error which is caused by my call...

```
$results = $db->select('pages','','','name',array('name', 'DESC'),'10',array('tags', '%' .$word. '%'));
```

(the select works as -- 'table','where','bind for where query match','fields','orderby array','limit',where/like array')

I think the problem is lying in the 'tags' field being an array. What is the best way to go about this? If necessary, I'm pulling each result up as so after the query:

```
//if we got something through $_POST
if (isset($_GET['search'])) {
// here you would normally include some database connection
require_once('../config/dbconfig.php');

// never trust what user wrote! We must ALWAYS sanitize user input
//$word = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['search']);
$word = htmlentities($_GET['search']);
// build your search query to the database
//$sql = "SELECT title, url FROM pages WHERE content LIKE '%" . $word . "%' ORDER BY title LIMIT 10";

$results = $db->select('pages','','','*',array('name', 'DESC'),'10',array('tags', '%' .$word. '%'));

// get results
if (count($results) > 0) {
    $end_result = '';
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach($results as $row) {
        $bold = '<span class="found">' .$word. '</span>';
        $end_result .= '<li>' .str_ireplace($word, $bold, $row['title']).   '</li>';
    }
    //echo $end_result. '</ul>';
}else {
    //echo '<ul><li>No results found</li></ul>';
}
var_dump($results);
exit;
}
```

It says the error is in my foreach:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

which every time so far has been because of my query before it. Every single time.

I searched and didn't see anything specifically like this, if I missed it I'm very sorry. Also I'm tired, so if I missed some details let me know and I will post them. Thanks!

This is how the select is processing before it hits run.

```
public function select($table, $where="", $bind="", $fields="*", $order="", $limit="", $like="") {
    $sql = "SELECT " . $fields . " FROM " . $table;
    if(!empty($where)) {
        $sql .= " WHERE " . $where;
    }
    if (!empty($order)) {
        $sql .= " ORDER BY " . $order[0] . " " . $order[1];
    }
    if (!empty($limit) && is_array($limit)) {
        $sql .= " LIMIT " . $limit[0] . " " . $limit[1];
    }
    if (!empty($limit)) {
        $sql .= " LIMIT " . $limit;
    }
    if (!empty($like)) {
        $sql .= " WHERE " .$like[0]. " LIKE " . $like[1];
    }
    $sql .= ";";
    //var_dump($sql);
    //var_dump($bind);
    //exit;
    return $this->run($sql, $bind);
}

public function run($sql, $bind="") {
    $this->sql = trim($sql);
    $this->bind = $this->cleanup($bind);
    $this->error = "";

    try {
        $pdostmt = $this->prepare($this->sql);
        if($pdostmt->execute($this->bind) !== false) {
            if(preg_match("/^(" . implode("|", array("select", "describe", "pragma")) . ") /i", $this->sql))
                return $pdostmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            elseif(preg_match("/^(" . implode("|", array("delete", "insert", "update")) . ") /i", $this->sql))
                return $pdostmt->rowCount();
        }   
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        $this->error = $e->getMessage();    
        $this->debug();
        return false;
    }
}
```

(switched to $_GET b/c the search is using AJAX and didn't feel like changing a bunch of stuff just to call it, so did it directly in the page with the url instead.)

nm on that query edit i just removed, it was right the first time... tired sorry...

Comment: What do you mean by the tags field being an array? An array is not a valid column type in MySQL.

Comment: Also, what type of object is `$db`? I'm not familiar with anything that has a `select()` method like that.

Comment: Terminology is probably wrong, an example of one of the fields in the table I'm using, named 'tags', value is: 'about, mission, what, is, imengine, studio'. I guess really its just a string with comments in it. $db is the object made to initiate the connection with the database. Using the the highly hated wrappers to keep connections. It works fine with the many, many other queries I have.

Comment: I'm sure `$db` works fine, but the problem is either in the parameters being passed to `select()` or in the object returned by it - neither of which I'm familiar with. If it's your own object, can you include a bit more detail about it?

Comment: What do you get if you `var_dump($results)` after the `select()` call?

Comment: What is the output of $results?

Comment: In my OP I put what each field is for, table, where, bind for where query, fields, orderby(field,asc/desc), limit, where/like as array-- in that order for the select query. If it's not needed, it's left blank. So doing something like: `SELECT firstname FROM friends WHERE firstname='boo'` would look like: `$db->select('friends','firstname=boo','','firstname','','','');`

Comment: bool(false) is what comes out with the error, which in this systems case means its not running the sql at all, which I'm pretty sure is because of the way the 'like' part of my query is compared to the value of the field in the database table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem is that you're using `count()` on a non-array value.

When a non-array is converted to an array, it becomes a single-element array containing the original value.

```
(array) 1234; // results in array(0 => 1234)
(array) "ABC" // results in array(0 => "ABC")
(array) false // results in array(0 => false)
```

So when you do `count($results)` when `$results` is `false`, the value will be converted to an array internally, and you're going to get `1` because it's a single-element array - and your code for processing the results will run instead of the `else` clause.

This is what's causing the `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` error message that you're seeing.

---

As for why it's returning false in the first place, let's take a look at the query that's being generated:

```
SELECT name FROM pages ORDER BY name DESC WHERE tags LIKE %someword%
```

There's actually a couple problems here:

1. Your word value is not getting quoted. So the query will end up ending with:

   ```
   WHERE tags LIKE %someword%
   ```

   So one error is caused by the missing quotes around `%someword%`.

   I would guess that this should be the responsibility of the `select()` function - along with escaping the value to prevent SQL injection, which is also missing.

   The best solution would probably be to have the `$like` parameter automatically use `?`, and add to the `$bind` values. I assume `$bind` is just an array, so you could do something like this:

   ```
   if (!empty($like)) {
       if (empty($bind)) $bind = array();
       $bind[] = $like[1];
       $sql .= " WHERE " .$like[0]. " LIKE ?"
   }
   ```
2. The `LIKE` condition is getting added to the end of the query - after any `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` clauses. This is also resulting in invalid SQL. If you need an extra parameter for `$like`, it should be processed at the same time as the existing `$where` condition, not after the order-by.

*Overall, I don't understand why you're using a 7th parameter for `$like`, instead of just passing `"tags LIKE ?"` into the existing `$where` parameter.*

---

Instead of guessing at what the error is that's causing it to return false, why not just take a look at the actual error message?

You're saving the error message before returning false... so if you add this to the beginning of your `if` condition:

```
if ($results === false) {
    echo($db->error);
} elseif (count($results) > 0) {
```

... you should be able to see exactly what PDO is complaining about.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, as I would have had issues later. :)
That isn't it thought, changed the search to include something I know will return more than one, and changed to just pull all records instead of just 'name' and still nothing.

Comment: added the extra stuff for like, but same result. Honestly, that's a very good point and I don't know why I didnt just put it in the WHERE lol, either way would still be having the same issue. Also added the run part of the code in the OP as well for the query, but I don't think it's the wrapper as it's been working fine with a news system, login/out/register, loading/editing/adding pages, etc. Something specifically in this query that has to do with the record having 'a, b, c, d' and stuff I think still, just don't know what because I've never done it like that before.

Comment: Oh boy... no and that fixed it. I'm really sorry about that but thank you very much! Can't believe I missed that.

Comment: @Grant glad we were able to help figure it out. I'd recommend doing something to show the actual PDO error message and possibly the actual query string to help track this type of thing down in the future. At the moment, it seems like you're returning false and not showing the error message anywhere.

Comment: Yeah, I just picked this back up. It's on my to do list. I really should have done it first though... kinda dumb lol.